# Bulk Insert Sql Server millions of record

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services, bulkinsert

I have a Windows Service application that receives a stream of data with the following format

```
IDX|20120512|075659|00000002|3|AALI                 |Astra Agro Lestari Tbk.                                     |0|ORDI_PREOPEN|12  |00000001550.00|00000001291.67|00001574745000|00001574745000|00500|XDS1BXO1|                                        |00001574745000|›§
IDX|20120512|075659|00000022|3|ALMI                 |Alumindo Light Metal Industry Tbk.                          |0|ORDI        |33  |00000001300.00|00000001300.00|00000308000000|00000308000000|00500|--U3---2|                                        |00000308000000|õÄ
```

This data comes in millions of rows and in sequence `00000002....00198562` and I have to parse and insert them according to the sequence into a database table.

My question is, what is the best way (the most effective) to insert these data into my database? I have tried to use a simple method as to open a SqlConnection object then generate a string of SQL insert script and then execute the script using SqlCommand object, however this method is taking too long.

I read that I can use Sql BULK INSERT but it has to read from a textfile, is it possible for this scenario to use BULK INSERT? (I have never used it before).

Thank you

update: I'm aware of SqlBulkCopy but it requires me to have DataTable first, is this good for performance? If possible I want to insert directly from my data source to SQL Server without having to use in memory DataTable.

Comment: What do you mean by "insert them according to the sequence"? Why does it matter what order you insert rows? They are stored in the order specified in the [clustered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131.aspx), regardless of insertion order.

Answer (score 22):

If you are writing this in C# you might want to look at the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class.

> Lets you efficiently bulk load a SQL Server table with data from another source.

Comment: ;) Amazing how people supposedly never look at the documentation - SqlBUlkCopy sort of springs out to at least check. Note: It is trivial (an hour) to write a converter that allows SqlBulkCopy to use an enumeration of objects as data source ;)

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer, I have updated my question. Could you comment on that please? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First, download free **LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv** library.

Second, use the code like this

```
StreamReader sr = new TextReader(yourStream);
var sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString);
sbc.WriteToServer(new LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv.CsvReader(sr));
```

Yeah, it is really that easy.

Comment: I was looking for a library that copes with CSV fields with embedded quotation marks and newlines. This CSVReader is perfect, and easily plugs into SqlBulkCopy.  I can now load millions of rows per minute using only a few lines of code. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Hi, How to insert values with check? e.g. I want to check whether the record exists or not in the db, if exists I want to append to other table

Comment: @NitinSawant It won't gonna be *bulk* insert any more. But a regular one-by-one.

Comment: @NitinSawant You need to change the processing idea - use bulk insert to push into Table A, you can then perform a join on your other table to drive the decision where to put it; databases should be used for set based operations, they perform really poorly on row based

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSIS "Sql Server Integration Service" for converting data from source data flow to destination data flow.
The source can be a text file and destination can be a SQL Server table. Your conversion executes in bulk insert mode.

Comment: Why is every word capitalised?!