# EF 5.0 - Large volume insert into table

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have a worktable that we use to store the merged/joined selections from other tables with a large volume of records (could be millions of rows).  If I have an entity mapping for this table - is there a way to insert results into this table without pulling the data across to my context in the app?  I would prefer to do this without handwriting the SQL (that's how it's done now).

A Stored Procedure is a consideration.

Thanks

Comment: Sure, you can insert as much as you want without ever reading one record. But for "large volume insert" EF is not the right tool. Look for "bulk insert" patterns.

Comment: agreed entity framework is very very slow when it comes to bulk insert you may want to look into the bulk insert tool in SqlClient tho 
see this similar post for an example of using it with csv files 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731179/bulk-insert-sql-server-millions-of-record